# DOM javascript Form Gender Radio button "on" value output

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, radio-button, getelementbyid

```js
function myfunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements;
  var para = x[0].value;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    para = para.concate(x[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = para;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  name<input type="textbox" name="fname"> email
  <input type="textbox" name="email"> number
  <input type="textbox" name="number"> Gender
  <input type="radio" name="gender" checked>Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
  <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()"> Click me</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I tried but i think there is a bug. I want to display whole line that the user enter but clicking it is not working. At mid, it was working but after not working. I want output as **jaykumar jay@123 111111 Male** . And also how to get **Gender** Male/Female in **demo**. Instead it is giving me only **"on"** .How to get value **Male** or **Female** in demo.

Comment: Well your console is saying `Uncaught TypeError: para.concate is not a function`, that's a good hint :)

Comment: I got that by  var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements;
            var para = x[0].value;
            for(var i=1;i<x.length;i++){
                para+= "  "+ x[i].value;
            }

Comment: but now I want to solve that Male/Female problem. Why it is showing "on"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't add value to `radio input`. According to [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> If you omit the value attribute in the HTML, the submitted form data assigns the value `on` to the group.

```js
function myfunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements;
    var para = x[0].value;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        para = para.concat(x[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = para;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    name<input type="textbox" name="fname"> email
    <input type="textbox" name="email"> number
    <input type="textbox" name="number"> Gender
    <input type="radio" checked id="male" name="gender" value="Male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()"> Click me</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a different treatment when it's a radio, in addition of adding the value for each radio

```js
function myfunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements;
  var para = x[0].value;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if ((x[i].type === 'radio' && x[i].checked) || x[i].type === 'text') {
      para = para.concate(x[i].value);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = para;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  name<input type="text" name="fname"> email
  <input type="text" name="email"> number
  <input type="text" name="number"> Gender
  <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" checked>Male
  <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender">Female
  <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()"> Click me</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```